# Reset FreeTextBox editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am using third party open source FreeTextbox (FTB) editor and i want to reset the textbox or make the textbox empty using javascript.

//HTML

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox1" BreakMode="LineBreak" DesignModeCss="~/FreeTextBox/DesignMode.css" Width="780px" Height="210px" AutoParseStyles="False" FormatHtmlTagsToXhtml="False" HtmlModeDefaultsToMonoSpaceFont="True" ClientIDMode="Static"></FTB:FreeTextBox>

<input type="button" value="Reset" id="buttonReset" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />

<script language="javascript">

$("#buttonReset").bind('click', function () {
          // Need the code here
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First u have to find the control and then reset it.

//Code

```
$("#buttonReset").bind('click', function () {
            if (FTB_API != null) {
                objFTBControl = FTB_API['FreeTextBox1'];
                if (objFTBControl) {
                    objFTBControl.SetHtml("");
                }
            }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it ll be work...

```
$("#buttonReset").bind('click', function () { 
     if (FTB_API != null) {
          objFTBControl = FTB_API['FreeTextBox1'];
          if (objFTBControl) {
                 objFTBControl.SetHtml("");
          }
     }             
 });
```